# Need advice on tuning the performance of a Haskell program

Tags: performance, haskell

I've written a program in Haskell to do reporting using a bunch of XML files as input. Each xml file contains details of a defect record. Unfortunately, I keep running into the "out of memory" issue.

I've put up the program here - https://github.com/ckkashyap/haskell-perf-repro

I use parsec - I used Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec first then switched to Text.Parsec ... looks like Text.Parsec needs more memory in my situation.

Anyway, I suspect that the real problem is in the way I parsing and approaching the problem. I'd appreciate some advice on how I can go about debugging this situation.

Regards,
Kashyap

Comment: You might want to look into `attoparsec`. It takes a little getting used to when coming from Parsec, but it can be very fast, and tends to use less memory.

Comment: Have you profiled it? See [chapter 5 of the GHC manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/profiling.html).

Comment: Profile, use a real XML parser (rather than rolling your own), switch to bytestring or text-based parsing rather than strings.

Comment: For my actual implementation, I've already switched to "xml" from hackage. I am trying to understand more the process of debugging such a situation. I am using the profiler - I can see for example that the parse function has an unhealthy growth - but am not sure what to do about it.